# Is there a R package that does spatial regularization?

Tags: r

By spatial regularization I mean the method described in

- Aitkinson and Curran (1995) "Defining an Optimal Size of Support
  for Remote Sensing Investigations", or
- Section 4.8 of Webster and Oliver (2007) *Geostatistics for Environmental Scientists*

which is a way of calculating the variogram of a spatial variable that has a different support to the observed one.

Comment: If there is it's probably called gstat or spdep.

Comment: I couldn't find it in any of them.

Comment: All of the tools to perform this type of analysis are available in R but you will very likely have to code it yourself.

Comment: "The way" is misleading: how one adjusts the variogram depends (very much) on the sizes, geometries, and orientations of both supports.  Without knowing these details it could be difficult to answer your question.

Comment: @whuber, I have changed 'the way' to 'a way'. Of course, your real point is for me to provide more detail rather than changing the language. Still, I would have thought if a package exist, it would be flexible enough for the user to specify all these as (s)he uses it. In my particular problem, the data is satellite image, so essentially raster of rectangular pixels. By 'different support' in my question I really just mean a coarser resolution of the same raster, rather than a completely different support. But this is all outlined in the first paper cited.

Answer (score 4):

"I couldn't find it in any of them" ?

[CRAN Task View: Analysis of Spatial Data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html) (Geostatistics)

You can also use the [SOS package](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/12/barug-sos-package.html) directly in R

```
 library(sos)
 # find packages with a "spatial regularization" function
 unique( findFn("spatial regularization")$Package )
 found 43 matches;  retrieving 3 pages
 2 3 
 Downloaded 29 links in 11 packages.
 [1] "MRIaggr"     "fdaPDE"      "SpatPCA"     "rtop"        "dti"         "Geneclust"   "mboost"      "adimpro"    
 [9] "gamboostLSS" "ppmlasso"    "Rquake"
```

And

```
library(sos)
unique( findFn("variogram")$Package )
found 491 matches;  retrieving 20 pages, 400 matches.
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
Downloaded 373 links in 66 packages.
[1] "RandomFields"       "gstat"              "ProbForecastGOP"   
[4] "geoR"               "georob"             "nlme"              
[7] "StatDA"             "npsp"               "rtop"              
[10] "geo"                "AFM"                "phylin"            
[13] "SpatialVx"          "ctmm"               "geofd"             
[16] "vardiag"            "sgeostat"           "compositions"      
[19] "GSIF"               "ltsk"               "EcoGenetics"       
[22] "usdm"               "CompRandFld"        "geospt"            
[25] "asremlPlus"         "sm"                 "EnviroStat"        
[28] "UncerIn2"           "synchrony"          "fractaldim"        
[31] "intamap"            "agridat"            "automap"           
[34] "joineR"             "fields"             "meteo"             
[37] "spatial"            "SpatialExtremes"    "spsann"            
[40] "pedometrics"        "intamapInteractive" "seeg"              
[43] "lmenssp"            "MarkedPointProcess" "mev"               
[46] "plotKML"            "spatstat"           "pastecs"           
[49] "prevR"              "SoPhy"              "GeoXp"             
[52] "raster"             "vegan"              "FeedbackTS"        
[55] "RcmdrPlugin.seeg"   "DiceDesign"         "ggmap"             
[58] "RSAGA"              "hydroTSM"           "kriging"           
[61] "constrainedKriging" "DiceKriging"        "EFDR"              
[64] "fda.usc"            "gear"               "geostatsp"
```

And you are spoiled for choice

Comment: Could you indicate which of these many choices provide tools for addressing the change-of-support problem that has been asked?

Comment: Simply an indication because qoheleth says "I couldn't find it in any of them"  about gstat or spdep and there are many libraries to study and understand , if he want...

Comment: @gene I have to commend you for introducing the SOS package. It seems like a useful package to know. My 'couldn't find it' is obviously, as you have noted, a response to mdsummer's comment, so no where have I intended for it to apply to all these other packages. As with your list, just because the key terms appear doesn't mean the package does what I want. In fact, the term 'regularization', even in the spatial context, often means other things (e.g. related to loss function). So, it would be useful if you have a specific recommendation.